# where to put interfaces and type aliases

Tags: angular

I use custom interfaces and type aliases in my `angular2` project. For example, I'm implementing a component that shows a products list, so I need to define  `Product` interface:

```
export interface Product {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    price: number;
}
```

Now I need a place to put interfaces into. I'm thinking it should be within a components folder. I've also peeked inside the sources, and angular seems to put all interfaces into `facade` folder. So I ended up with the following structure:

```
components
|
|--- product-list
     |
     |--- facade
     |    |
     |    |--- product.ts
     |
     |--- product-list.component.ts
     |--- product-list.component.html
     |--- product-list.component.css
```

The interface is used like this:

```
export class RowComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() product: Product;
    @Output() productRemoved: EventEmitter<ProductRemoved> = new EventEmitter();

    constructor() {
    }
```

Is this a viable approach? Are there any styles guides specific to the matter in question?

Comment: How exactly is this interface used? Is it implemented by some class?

Comment: What's `product`? If it is an instance of some class, `interface` may be redundant. If it is used by components outside `product-list`, it is reasonable to put it into 'shared'. If it's not, it may be inside `product-list.component.ts`.

Comment: @estus, yes, an interface is used to validate the object created with object literal. But it's a simple object with just three properties, I don't want to create a class for it

Comment: It is recommended to use abstract classes for everything, https://angular.io/styleguide#!#03-03 . However, I stick to interfaces for now because tree shaking is broken in Webpack. As a rule of thumb, I prefer to keep interface in primary location (e.g. product-list.component.ts) until it is imported from outside more than once. Then it can be moved to `shared` or whatever.

Comment: @estus, so the answer provided by Branko makes sense, correct?

Comment: The answer presumes that you have Product class, because it is convenient to keep an interface near the place where it is used. If you don't have a model class, having a separate file for really simple interface looks like overkill to me.

Answer (score 36):

I struggled with this too. The first thing to understand is that directory structure is pretty subjective on your use-case and project complexity. That said, the official documentation has some good guidelines to get started:

https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-04-06

I use the following structure for medium to large apps:

```
|-- app
     |-- modules
       |-- home
           |-- [+] components
           |-- [+] pages
           |-- home-routing.module.ts
           |-- home.module.ts
     |-- core
       |-- [+] authentication
       |-- [+] footer
       |-- [+] guards
       |-- [+] mocks
       |-- [+] models // <- here
       |-- [+] validators
       |-- [+] services
       |-- core.module.ts
       |-- ensureModuleLoadedOnceGuard.ts
       |-- logger.service.ts
     |
     |-- shared
          |-- [+] components
          |-- [+] directives
          |-- [+] pipes
     |
     |-- [+] configs
|-- assets
     |-- scss
          |-- [+] partials
          |-- _base.scss
          |-- styles.scss
```

Most of the time your services (in Core module) will consume your model interfaces, and your components in-turn will communicate only with the modeled data through the service. In smaller applications, putting the data model interface at the top of the Service file makes the most sense. However, as your application becomes larger, there will be instances where the components need the data model interface and not the service.

Keeping the data model interfaces provides the most sustainable approach, that provides the best "separation of concerns" and abstraction.

This [article](https://itnext.io/choosing-a-highly-scalable-folder-structure-in-angular-d987de65ec7) goes into detail about structuring Angular 6 apps.

Answer (score 4):

IMHO simplest and easiest solution is to place it in same file above model class.

```
interface ProductJson {
   id: number;
   name: string;
   price: number;
}

export class Product{
    constructor(private id:number,
                private name:String,
                private price:number){}


    public static fromJson(productJson : ProductJson ) : Product {
           //
    }
}
```

EDIT : As for folder structure :

```
 product-list
 |
 |--- component
 |    |
 |    |--- product-list.component.ts
 |    |--- product-list.component.html
 |    |--- product-list.component.css
 |
 |--- model
 |    |
 |    |--- product.ts
 |
 |--- service
      |
      |--- product-service.ts
```

etc..

This is what i do.

Comment: thanks, but in this way the interface can't be reused

Comment: True. But fields id,name,price. Hardly represent anything else than product. For simplicity if i have dedicated interface, like in this case i go, with this structure. For more Generic interfaces creating extra file and placing it in core/model seems fine.

Comment: all right, got it, thanks. so `model` folder name is probably better than `facade`?

Comment: I`ve seen people use it. Makes sense to me so i`have adopted it.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is a personal preference. I find practical to keep some interfaces in a global shared directory and some of them in module directory. For example globals in "core/models/core.models.ts" and specific ones in "modules/home/home.models.ts".